# filterVarImp - Caret Package

Tags: r, categorical-data, feature-selection, caret

I was trying the `filterVarImp` function in `caret` package. While the outcome was categorical we get ROC as the importance measure. My question is: How is the function doing it? Is it fitting a model and then predicting probabilities to compare with target to give AUC or comparing itself directly? How is categorical predictor handled here?

Comment: Why not read the documentation, or even examine the underlying code? At any rate, questions about how R (R functions) works are off topic here.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the function can be accessed using:

```
?filterVarImp
```

It states the following:

> For classification, ROC curve analysis is conducted on each predictor.
>   For two class problems, a series of cutoffs is applied to the
>   predictor data to predict the class. The sensitivity and specificity
>   are computed for each cutoff and the ROC curve is computed. The
>   trapezoidal rule is used to compute the area under the ROC curve. This
>   area is used as the measure of variable importance.

For categorical predictors, one can imagine the function is using a similar approach. It just needs to have some kind of order to apply a series of cutoffs. This could be obtained using factor levels or alphabetical ordering.

Here is an example:

```
testDf <- data.frame(x1 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 54), 
                     x2 = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"), 
                     x3 = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"),
                     y = c("N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y"))
filterVarImp(x = testDf[, -4], 
             y = testDf$y)
```

That gives the following output:

```
           N         Y
x1 0.9444444 0.9444444
x2 0.6666667 0.6666667
x3 0.5000000 0.5000000
```

But I am seeing that this function can be misleading if the output levels are flipped. For example if you flip the output variable levels like this:

```
testDf <- data.frame(x1 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 54), 
                     x2 = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"), 
                     x3 = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"),
                     y = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N")
                     )
filterVarImp(x = testDf[, -4], 
             y = testDf$y)
```

the output becomes:

```
            N          Y
x1 0.05555556 0.05555556
x2 0.33333333 0.33333333
x3 0.50000000 0.50000000
```

AUCs under 0.5 need to be subtracted from 1 to get the true AUC.